# Writing SQL Unpivot operator for multiple columns - data stacking

Tags: sql

I am trying to stack a data set using the UNPIVOT operator in SQL, but do not know how to perform the operator when there are multiple columns that need to be unpivoted.

This is the current data structure:

[image: Input]

This is my desired output:

[image: Output]

Can anyone help me write the SQL code for to pull data into the unpivoted structure?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very poor data format.  One method is to just query each combination as a separate query and glue them together with `union all`:

```
select product, 'Europe' as location, 'Heat Resistant' as properties, 'white' as color
from t
where europe = 'x' and heat_resistant = 'x' and white = 'x'
union all
select product, 'Europe' as location, 'Heat Resistant' as properties, 'blue' as color
from t
where europe = 'x' and heat_resistant = 'x' and blue = 'x'
union all
select product, 'Europe' as location, 'Moisure Resistant' as properties, 'white' as color
from t
where europe = 'x' and moisure_resistant = 'x' and white = 'x'
union all
. . .
```

Some databases support lateral joins, which would simplify the logic a bit.  But you haven't specified your database.